# Spring MVC path with placeholder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Currently we are able to define the path of a Spring MVC endpoint with the placeholder:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "${my.path}")
```

I would like to have the same behavior but multiple paths with only one property in the placeholder, like below:

```
.properties
my.paths = /foo /bar # two paths /foo and /bar for the same endpoint

.java
@RequestMapping(path = {"${my.path}"})
```

But i don't find any way with the ant-path style, supported by Spring, to handle my use case.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to load paths from a properties file; it has to be const.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Value("${my.path}")
private String yourPath;

@RequestMapping(path = yourPath)
```

Is this not workig for you ?

Comment: Nop, the annotation value should be a constant (`private static final`)

Comment: according to the javadoc place holders should be allowed in the RequestMapping path attribute
Path mapping URIs may contain placeholders (e.g. "/${connect}") Supported at the type level as well as at the method level!</b>

Comment: The code does not work. `...Compilation failure... element value must be a constant expression...`